# Is it possible to perform a serializer relation in Django Rest Framework where models are running on different apps?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have these two models which are running on different app within my Django Rest Framework (v3.14) project.

How can I implement the serializer for this? Also, I am open for your suggestions, if this is not possible. TIA

What I have tried so far:

Model (App1):

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
```

Model (App2):

```
class Items(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    transno = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    barcode = models.ForeignKey("app1.Model1", to_field="barcode", db_column="barcode", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="app2_items")
```

What I wanted to do?

Display an output like this (upon GET Request):

```
    [
        {
            created: "2023-05-26 00:00:00",
            updated: "2023-05-26 00:00:00",
            transno: "123456",
            model1: {
                created: "2023-05-26 00:00:00",
                updated: "2023-05-26 00:00:00",
                barcode: "123134",
                shortname: ""
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 separate serializers. One for `Items` and another one for `Model1`.

in `app1/serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'
```

another one in `app2/serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app1.serializers import Model1Serializer

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    barcode = Model1Serializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now you can use the `ItemSerializer` to return the data along with the details of barcode.